# Force Django to commit

Tags: mysql, django, transactions, commit

**Setup:**

- Python script **A** inserts data to a database every 15 minutes
- Python script **B** queries a few of the latest entries from the database every few minutes

Both use Django's ORM, run on the same machine and use a local MySQL database.

**The Problem:** 
**B** fetches entries, except for the latest one, even though **A** saves it *minutes* before.

I suspected that **A** doesn't close the transaction, thus **B** sees the database without the last entry. Indeed when examining the MySQL logs, I noticed the `commit` for each `INSERT` happens right before the *next* `INSERT`.

Even though it's supposed to be redundant, I added `@commit_on_success` decorator to the **A** function that includes the `save()`, but it did not help.

How can I force Django (or MySQL?!) to commit right after the `save()`?

**UPDATE:** 
I discovered that the commits *DO* happen - I was mislead to believe they don't because [MySQL's General Query Log only has 1 sec resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025847/mysql-general-query-log-entry-order). 
In light of this and other new information, I've reasked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028091/django-orm-queries-fail-to-select-new-objects).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `commit_manually` decorator and call it whenever you want.

Straight from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually):

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually
def viewfunc(request):
    ...
    # You can commit/rollback however and whenever you want
    transaction.commit()
    ...

    # But you've got to remember to do it yourself!
    try:
        ...
    except:
        transaction.rollback()
    else:
        transaction.commit()
```

This answers the question you *asked*, though I wonder if there might be something else at work.

NOTE: `commit_manually` was deprecated in [1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.6/#deprecated-features-1-6) and removed in [1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-8).

Comment: How would that be different than `@commit_on_success`? (switching to manual commit will hurt our uptime, so I'd like to better understand in advance before tempering with the system)

Comment: `commit_on_success` only runs the commit after the wrapped function returns; if it's sitting idle without returning it won't help. `commit_manually` lets you call the commit right after the last save. I'm not sure what your code is doing, so that's all I can think of right now.

Comment: Although I discovered my problem was elsewhere, I do believe your answer to be significant for those searching for forcing django commits, therefore I marked it as the right answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by that MySQL by default has a REPEATABLE-READ transaction isolation level. That means that the same query is expected to return the same values. Changes won't return. You can do two things here:

1. Set transaction isolation level to READ-COMMITTED in the settings. As explained [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14026).
2. Force a commit, thus close the transaction on script B, so as a new transaction starts, you will see all changes before this new transaction. `Model.objects.update()` does the trick.