# MySQL general query log entry order

Tags: mysql, logging

When directing MySQL's [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) to a `general_log` table, it has an `event_time` column of type `timestamp` - which has a resolution of 1sec. Also there is no auto-increment `id` column.

If multiple log entries have the same timestamp (occur on same second) - how can I know their order?

(If you know of a completely different approach to logging the queries by their order, please do share as well)

Comment: auto increment only happen after the record is inserted ... what I think you can verify against replication binary log (if you enable that)

Comment: From the reference - *mysqld writes statements to the query log in the order that it receives them, which might differ from the order in which they are executed.*

Comment: @Devart - that's horrible :( Is there no hope?

Comment: @Jonathan: only replication binlog if you want such precision

Comment: @ajreal - Thanks - I wasn't aware of the binary log. I'll give it a try...

Comment: Guys, if one of you will sum all the info in the comments to an answer, I'll accept it. If you won't I'll do it, but the credit should be yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing up my understandings and the comments above:

- General Query Log (GQL) entries are written in the order received, which might differ from the order in which they are executed
- Indeed GQL has a resolution of only 1sec
- MySQL's [binary log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html) seems the only way to get better resolution