# Django ORM queries fail to select new objects

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

**Setup:**

- Python script **A** inserts data to a DB every round 15 minutes
- Python script **B** queries for the last 5 entries every few minutes

Both use django's ORM, same MySQL DB and the same DB user account (same `settings.py` file)

**The Problem:**
**B** is able to fetch only entries inserted before it was run. As if **B** is running with a frozen DB, frozen at the moment **B** first connected to the DB.

How come?
Can I control this behavior in django?

Comment: **B** uses the the following syntax to query: `MyModel.objects.filter(a_datetime_field__gte=datetime.datetime(2011,08,11,14,15,0)).order_by('a_datetime_field')`

Comment: If you're using MySQL and InnoDB be aware that the default isolation level is REPEATABLE-READ. You may prefer to have READ-COMMITED. See this answer for an alternative solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346124/how-do-i-force-django-to-ignore-any-caches-and-reload-data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're reusing same Manager object, you have to keep in mind [it's caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets). To deal with that you have to manually update.

This will return same results in every iteration:

```
while True:
   same_every_time = AClass.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]
   sleep(300)
```

In order to make it work properly you have to add the update:

```
while True:
   AClass.objects.update()
   updated_results = AClass.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]
   sleep(300)
```

Comment: That worked!! I can't seem to find documentation about this - Any chance you could post a reference?

Comment: I've added link to caching documentation. I'm not sure where I found the `.update()` solution, I was looking everywhere for way to invalidate that cache. I found it on some Django forum, but can't recall where now. I have this in production code and works perfectly.

Comment: REPEATABLE-READ transaction isolation level (MySQL default), and no commits on SELECT statements would also explain this problem. But objects.update() resolves that as well...

Answer (score 0):

Django by itself uses a sort of container-managed persistence. This means that the database transactions are committed by the middleware during the upstream response cascade.

If you are usiong Django ORM by itself, you should ensure actual committing of the transaction:

```
from django.db import transaction

def my_task(whatever):
    MyModel.objects.create(...)
    # do whatever
    transaction.commit()
    return 'my_result'
```

Comment: I've insured commit in many ways - using `@commit_on_success`, by viewing the data by myself in realtime, by going through the MySQL logs... The problem isn't in the insertion but in the querying of the data

Comment: In fact probably the correct point is in @vartec answer. Managers use an internal cache, that's used normally during the request/response cycle so data is always consistent, but on the other side for a long-running script you should invalidate it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this stackoverflow question when trying to solve a similar situation with *Django tests*: in the test, I modified Django model objects, but the changes were not reflected in the database so that the database reader in the second thread could detect the changes. The solution was to inherit my test class from [TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase) instead of the default django.test.TestCase.